# Should we use the [studies] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Considering that the site is about *Language Learning*, studies is inferred.

Should we use the tag at all?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[studies](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/studies), to me, means "studies, published in a peer reviewed journal".  Not "I'm doing my language studies before bed."

Perhaps a less ambiguous tag can be used for this.  I like @Gille's suggestion of [reference-request](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request). It doesn't have the ambiguity shortcomings of [research](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) (is the question asking about results of past research, or how to conduct research, etc)?

Comment: This is a good point. I think there should definitely be a better name for it.

Comment: In an ideal world, wouldn't *every* answer cite studies?  Perhaps some topics simply haven't been studied, but I'd think that any answer would benefit from one.  So why call this out in a tag?

Comment: @Nathaniel: I don't think it's fair to assume that all types of questions call for studies. "What is SRS?" doesn't need a study. "How do I test for the TOEFL?" doesn't need studies.  Many questions, however, will need studies... and perhaps it an expectation can be built into the site, which would make such a tag meaningless.

Comment: Wouldn't [tag:research] fit better the definition you propose?

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin: to me that, sounds like it's about the act of doing research.  "How would I conduct an experiment to test X hypothesis?" seems like a candidate for [research] to me.

Comment: should we go the long way and get a [tag:published-studies]?

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin: Maybe, but might I suggest first a wiki tag entry, and see what happens? There are only 4 open questions with that tag presently, and they all fit my definition of the term. Can we leave things as they are unless/until a problem is truly shown to exist?

Comment: @Flimzy well I do find it ambiguous. But we might give it a bit of time...

Comment: @Flimzy it'll only continue to get worse, best to fix it while the questions are in the single digits

Comment: @Quill: "Continue to get worse" implies an existing problem. What evidence do you have that the tag is being misused now?

Comment: The tag description is incorrect, and [this meta question](http://meta.languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/56/can-we-change-the-studies-tag-to-scientific-research) and [this chat message](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28785463#28785463) all are examples of misinterpreting/miscommunication of the tag's intention

Comment: @Quill: I've submitted an edit to the description. It's awaiting approval.

Comment: Many Stack Exchange sites use [tag:reference-request] for this, I think it's the de facto standard and it would be somewhat confusing for people who visit multiple sites to have a different tag name here.

Comment: @Gilles: I like that suggestion.

Comment: @Gilles: Perhaps you should provide that as an answer, so it can be unambiguously voted upon.

Answer (score 5):

### [studies](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/studies) has no purpose delete it

Reasons:

- It is inferred from our question title
- It is like [homework](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) on Math.SE and will probably inevitably be deleted.
- [studies](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/studies) refers to almost the entire scope of the site

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think it's necessary. As you said, I think studying is implied given the context of the site.

Answer (score -2):

I say we use the [scientific-research](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scientific-research) that I've created. It's clear and unambiguous unlike [studies](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/studies) which could be misinterpreted in a number of ways.

And I say this as the second highest asker of the tag [studies](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/studies).

Comment: I also like the tag "published-studies"

Comment: [scientific-research] is ambiguous, but in a different way. "How can I conduct an experiment to test X hypothesis?" would be appropriate for a [scientific-research] tag.  I like @Gille's suggestion to use [reference-request].

Answer (score -3):

I don't like the word "studies." It is basically implied by the site, that we are "studying" languages.

A better usage might be something like "field," or "discipline." That would imply some "subset" of language learning.

Answer (score -4):

`Peer-reviewed-evidence` might be a more precise tag for the same purpose.

Comment: It is. But do we want only peer-reviewed one? And the other possible problem being that people are unlikely to find it as suggested tag.

Comment: There are some answers where only peer-reviewed evidence is requested. It could be useful to have a special tag for those cases.