# About the tags [reference-request], [published-studies] and [learning-methods]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Thought it is clear that those tags can be used for different things I think there is some overlapping.

### [reference-request](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) and [published-studies](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/published-studies)

Since a study can be used as a reference and a reference can be either a book based on some studies or only one study it seems clear that reference and a study can be the same thing.

### [reference-request](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) and [learning-methods](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning-methods)

*Learning methods* in itself can be pretty vague and can refer to either a book, a collection of software or to learning techniques. On the other hand, *reference* overlaps the previous tags because the concept of *reference* overlaps the above-cited meanings of *learning-methods* save for the techniques part.

### [published-studies](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/published-studies) and [learning-methods](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning-methods)

Here I don't think there is any overlapping.

---

My conclusion is that [reference-request](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) overlaps with at least to tags. Thus I wonder if we had better not using it.

The [learning-methods](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning-methods) have already be given a tag guidance whereas the two others have not.

I would suggest the following tag guidance for [published-studies](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/published-studies):

> Ask for published scientific studies which address the problematic asked by the question.

On the other hand, the vagueness in *reference-request* prevent me from giving a satisfying definition

Comment: I don't see any relationship at all between [published-studies] and [learning-methods].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overlap between [reference-request](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) and [published-studies](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/published-studies) is partly my fault.

We'd been discussing dropping the [studies](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/studies) tag on Meta, but we hadn't agreed on a replacement tag or general solution yet.

I liked bilbo_pengouin's [suggestion](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/should-we-use-the-studies-tag#comment29_26) of [published-studies](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/published-studies) and I had a question to tag with it, so I used it.

A little bit after that, Gilles suggested using [reference-request](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request), which seems to be the standard on other SE sites, so that tag was put in place by a few people.

As with Meta discussions, I usually prefer to let a discussion ferment rather than accept the first decent answer to get a law in place. However the time wait on this kinda messed up how I chose the tags, so I've gone with the [reference-request](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) answer, and we can put that in place now.

At this point, it would be excellent to tag synonymise [published-studies](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/published-studies) as a synonym of [reference-request](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request), however that's a CM-exclusive power until someone gets the rep (and tag rep) to do so.

I will go and edit all of the [published-studies](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/published-studies) tags to use [reference-request](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) instead.